# Resolving implementation of "Super interface" in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

Maybe not even possible but here's my need.
I have a generic implementation of a key mapper, and a Factory class capable of generating such mappers

```cs
public class KeyMapperFactory 
{
    IKeyMapper<TInternalKey, TExternalKey> GetMapper<TInternalKey, TExternalKey>(MapperConfig config)
}
```

Now I would like to have interfaces that "speak clear" in the application so I would create another empty interface in my app like this

```cs
public interface IMapCompanyToPayrollCompany : IKeyMapper<CompanyId, PayrollCompanyId>
{
}
```

Do I have any chances to create an "on the fly" implementation of `IMapCompanyToPayrollCompany` using CastleWindsor in something like this (wrong) way ?

```cs
var mapperConfig = MapperConfig {
...
};
var keyMapperFactory = new KeyMapperFactory();
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Register(
    Component
        .For<IMapCompanyToPayrollCompany>()
        .UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => (IMapCompanyToPayrollCompany)keyMapperFactory.GetMapper<CompanyId, PayrollCompanyId>(mapperConfig)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using Castle's DynamicProxies

```cs
// I developed an extension method on the IWindsorContainer
public static void RegisterMapper<TSpeakingInterface, TInternal, TExternal>(this IWindsorContainer container, MapperConfig config) 
    where TSpeakingInterface : IKeyMapper<TInternal, TExternal>
{
    container.Register(
        Component
            .For<TSpeakingInterface>()
            .UsingFactoryMethod(() => {
                var generator = new ProxyGenerator(); // <--Documentation recommend this to be a Singleton for performance and memory reason ... 
                var keyMapperFactory = new KeyMapperFactory();
                var mapper = keyMapperFactory.GetMapper<TInternal, TExternal>(config);
                var interceptor = new KeyMapperInterceptor<TInternal, TExternal>(mapper);

                // see: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/issues/224
                var nullProxy = generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithoutTarget<TSpeakingInterface>();
                return generator.CreateInterfaceProxyWithTarget(nullProxy, interceptor);
            })
    );
}

// Now I can register a mapper this way:
var container = new WindsorContainer();
var config = new MapperConfig {
    [...] // mapper config stuff here
}
container.RegisterMapper<IMapCompanyToPayrollCompany, CompanyId, PayrollCompanyId>(config);
```

The interceptor is simple as this

```cs
public class KeyMapperInterceptor<TInternal, TExternal> : IInterceptor
{
   private readonly IKeyMapper<TInternal, TExternal> realMapper;

   public KeyMapperInterceptor(IKeyMapper<TInternal, TExternal> realMapper)
   {
       this.realMapper = realMapper;
   }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
       // We simply call the corresponding method on the realMapper
       var method = invocation.Method;
       invocation.ReturnValue = method.Invoke(realMapper, invocation.Arguments);
    }
}
```

... and it works !
Of course additional methods or properties are not allowed in the `IMapCompanyToPayrollCompany` because the interceptor will try to execute/access them on the "realMapper" which does not know anything about!